# Uper Limit of a Test being translated with Microsoft Translation API

Tags: c#, bing-api, microsoft-translator

I'm creating a WS which succesfully use the Microsoft Bing translation api to translate database content. Does anybody knows which is the max lenght a text passed in for translation to this api?. I was not able to find it out on MS documentation yet. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Translator API can be used directly via software or web sites using any of four interfaces: a Web widget, AJAX, HTTP, or SOAP and there are limits with each.

With AJAX, you can pass a TranslateArray with Ajax Service V2:
http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/TranslateArray

An array containing the texts for translation. All strings must be of the same language. The total of all texts to be translated must not exceed 10000 characters. The maximum number of array elements is 2000.

With Bing Translate API and Windows Azure Data Market Service (TranslatorContainer.cs) you can actually pass upto 1000 characters string at once also.

With HTTP/SOAP you can pass between 2000 and 5000 characters per request in order to optimize throughput and response times.